# I lose “unicodeness” when qDebug()ing after instancing a QApplication

Tags: qt, unicode

I am losing the capability of printing unicode characters right after instancing a QApplication object.

From the following code and having included all the needed libraries:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    qDebug() << "aeiou áéíóú";
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "aeiou áéíóú";
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
aeiou áéíóú
aeiou Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº
```

How do I fix this odd behaviour? I need to be able to print unicode strings (coming in UTF-8).

Comment: @HostileFork Yes they are all in UTF-8, I learned to do that when Web-Developing, it is not fun to serve UTF-8 encoded documents with files being in latin1 and not knowing it. lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **2017 UPDATE**: This answer from 2011 applies for Qt 4.  In Qt 5, the text codecs were eliminated, and all source is expected to be UTF-8.  See ["Source code must be UTF-8 and QString wants it"](http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/05/source-code-must-be-utf-8-and-qstring-wants-it/)

When Qt interprets `char *` into a string, it uses a text codec.  This is set globally, and you can choose what you want for your project:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#setCodecForCStrings

Note that Qt's default is Latin-1, and it may establish that default in the QApplication constructor call stack somewhere.  If you're globally using UTF-8 in your project, you might try:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    qDebug() << "aeiou áéíóú";

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);

    qDebug() << "aeiou áéíóú";
    return 0;
}
```

And see if that solves your issue.